# Does Google Colab use GPU for NLTK based lemmatization?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, lemmatization

I'm trying to run below given piece of code on Google Colab, here the `corpus['text']` is obtained by executing `Corpus['text']= [word_tokenize(entry) for entry in Corpus['text']]`. Note that before executing the above line, `Corpus['text']` was a dataframe consisting of 1M sentences, now it contains tokenized words. So now when I try to run the below code, it is taking so much time. I want to know whether this code is utilizing the GPU provided by Google Colab or not. If not, what can I do to increase the preprocessing of this dataset; suggest something other than reducing the dataset.

```
for index,entry in tqdm(enumerate(Corpus['text'])):
# Declaring Empty List to store the words that follow the rules for this step
Final_words = []
# Initializing WordNetLemmatizer()
word_Lemmatized = WordNetLemmatizer()
# pos_tag function below will provide the 'tag' i.e if the word is Noun(N) or Verb(V) or something else.
for word, tag in pos_tag(entry):
    # Below condition is to check for Stop words and consider only alphabets
    if word not in stopwords.words('english') and word.isalpha():
        word_Final = word_Lemmatized.lemmatize(word,tag_map[tag[0]])
        Final_words.append(word_Final)
# The final processed set of words for each iteration will be stored in 'text_final'
Corpus.loc[index,'text_final'] = str(Final_words)
```

Note: I've wrapped my iterator with tqdm, and it shows a speed of about 30it/s. And, according to that it'll take about 10-11 hours to lemmatize this dataset.
Also, can GPUs only be used for training purposes, and not for these type of loops?

Answer (score 0):

Something like lematization will not be done on the GPU.  Your issue is likely the line where you check for stopwords.  NLTK stopwords is a list which is very slow to check in a loop.  Try converting it to a set with something like this...

```
# Put this at the top
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# Make this your loop
if word.lower() not in stops and word.isalpha():
```

Notice that I put in `word.lower()`.  This is fairly standard so you can still catch a capitalized `The`, etc..

Comment: I agree with your method of using sets but it doesn't seem to help with the time required. Actually, I just started today without sets and I got a speed of about 135it/s. But when I used sets, the speed was almost the same initially but it deprecated gradually. I don't know how the speed enhanced, maybe because I halved the dataset size?